# How to get userinput values to a list using stdin

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to get user inputs to a list in python. The input is like:

```
2
3
4
5
```

So I want to stop inserting values to the array from value `5`.
I tried this code as shown below:

```
X=[]

for line in sys.stdin:
    line = line.strip()
    X.append(line)

print(X)
```

After I input values, program keeps waiting for next input. It doesn't print `X`.

Comment: You should use a while loop `while len(x) < 5:`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved using a `break` as below.

```
if(len(x)==5):
    break
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
a = [input() for x in range(5)]
print(a)
```